# How can I replace the text of this button only

Tags: jquery

How can I replace the text of this button only. I do not understand the behavior of this button. And this is all the code I came up with to solve this issue

```js
$('.for_whom .close').click(function(z) {
    
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('body .for .close').removeClass('active');
    $('body .for .close').text('No');

  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('body .for .close').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).text('Yes').css('margin-top', '30px');
  }    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="for">
    <button class="close">No</button>
  </div>
  <div class="for">
    <button class="close">No</button>
  </div>
  <div class="for">
    <button class="close">No</button>
  </div>
  <div class="for">
    <button class="close">No</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: And where `.for_whom` class exist in the html?

Comment: Which button?  There are 4 identical buttons.  Do you mean the button being clicked?  That's `$(this)`, which you are *already* using.  `$(this).text("maybe");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the class of the parent `div` to the button elements is `.for`, not `.for_whom`. This is why your code appears to do nothing.

You can also make the logic more succinct by using `toggleClass()`, and providing a function to `text()` which reads if the clicked button already has the `.active` class. Try this:

```js
var $buttons = $('.for .close').click(function(z) {
  $buttons.not(this).removeClass('active').text('No');
  $(this).text(function() {
    return $(this).hasClass('active') ? 'No' : 'Yes';
  }).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="for"><button class="close">No</button></div>
  <div class="for"><button class="close">No</button></div>
  <div class="for"><button class="close">No</button></div>
  <div class="for"><button class="close">No</button></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/sudakatux/dwqg4v00/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(z) {

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).text('No');

            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
                 $(this).text('Yes').css('margin-top', '30px');
            }               

        });
  })
```

If i understood the question correctly you want to toggle between yes and no,

I change your selectros a bit since you are only interested in the buttons. but you are on the right track so you'll get the idea. note that the `this` keyword is for the handler you previously put to that button. meaning the `this` is for the clicked button.

Hope it helps